# How do I create an encrypted growable disk image?

Tags: 13.04, encryption, iso, disk-image

I don't want to encrypt my whole home directory, just my work folder. So I figured that having my work stuff in an encrypted ISO would be a good idea.

How do I create an ISO?
How do I encrypt that iso?
How do I make the iso grow as the contents grow? (having it only take up as much space as it needs to)

Comment: Why do you want to have your work files in a ISO file system?
ISO file systems are designed for fixed size, non changing, file systems.  Even though you can change files in a ISO file, you don't remove anything, you just add a new version in the unused area of the file system (like on RW CDROM).

Comment: You can [setup an ecrypted directory](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory) Private, that stores its encrypted files under .Private

Comment: @Anders, what about sparse image? it doesn't have to be an ISO, but that's the only format I know of that is cross platform.

Comment: @Sylwester: how customizable is this? I saw that it would auto-decrypt on login. which is neat.

It would be cool to have the folder unmount after so much time of inactivity. 
I have my laptop in public quite a bit, and .. well even at work, if I'm not at my computer, it would be nice to close the encrypted folder, on unmount it, so it's just an encrypted blob

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli I've created an answer with `encfs` as an alternative, which has automatic unmount after n minutes idle time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since EncFs is deemed unsecure it is not adviced to use it. It's planned to be fixed in the next version, but it would be unwise to start using it now while it's insecure. eCryptfs is secure and you can have a private directory in your home dir with:

```
ecryptfs-setup-private --noautomount
```

And follow the direction. It will make .Private as encrypted directory and Private as the where it's mounted. With the option `--noautomount` it won't mount until you doubleclick "Access my private data" inside the Private directory.

**Old answer**

*The current version of EncFs has known security flaws covered in January 2014. Please [read the report](https://defuse.ca/audits/encfs.htm) before preceding using EncFs.*

Based on you comments you should have a look at [encfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EncFS). I have been using this long before Ubuntu got `ecyptfs` and even though I keep my files private under `~/Private` today I still have my old `~/safe` which i use for sensitive information that doesn't need to be mounted all the time.

```
# install encfs
sudo apt-get install encfs

# setup. directories need to be absolute paths
SAFE=~/safe
SAFE_ENC=~/.safe
mkdir $SAFE
mkdir $SAFE_ENC

# this is for mounting the fs (or create for first time mount)
encfs -i 10 $SAFE_ENC $SAFE
```

The first time you run this you'll be asked if you want to create a new encrypted filesystem. Just pressiong <kbd>RETURN</kbd> creates one with default options. The option `-i 10` will make the drive get unmounted if there has been ten minutes of inactivity. Remember not to do `cd $SAFE` or to keep it open in a file manager since it's considered activity.

If you have several systems that are going to access this (eg. by having $SAFE_ENC in a cloud storage) you should create it with the oldest version of Ubuntu you have or else it might not work on that system if it gets created with a newer system. (it's possible but you need to specify options that are compatible) I've used this since 2006 and am very happy with it.

Encfs has several applications. E.g. lately I have started using it for my USB thumb drive as well. I have a 16GB thumb that has 2GB live ubuntu-presistence with a 14GB which the live system mounts after asking for password. When using it from other systems i mount the drive manually in the terminal, but it would be trivial to get my systems to identify it as my safe drive and mount it with my keyring. I also mount it on my Windows work machine.

When setting this up I found there are some supplimentary packages that can be used to manage encfs from the desktop environment and get it mouted like ecryptfs.

Comment: this sounds fantastic, I'll definitely try it out.

Comment: what is SAFE_ENC? 
is that where the key file is stored?
I'm just wondering where the data is stored, cause I want to move my work folder to a different internal volume, but *if* there is a key file, I want that in my home folder.

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli No, it's the directory where the encrypted files are stored. It can be anywhere you have read/write access. I have one of mine in a dropbox folder, but any place will do and since it'secrypted you back it up with your unsafe files.

Comment: I found this guide super helpful :-) http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=148600

Comment: thx @Sylwester, this is a good alternative instead of truecrypt

Comment: There are security vulnerabilities in the current version of EncFS, see https://defuse.ca/audits/encfs.htm . Alternatives would be https://www.cryfs.org or http://ecryptfs.org

Comment: @Heinzi The same people did a audit of [eCryptfs](https://defuse.ca/audits/ecryptfs.htm) which seems passed for  the current CBC block mode.  I can't find any vouching for CryFS anywhere so you'll just have to take their word for it or pay someone to do an audit to make sure it's better choice than EncFs. Know i posted this answer long before the audit was done.

Comment: eCryptfs doesn't have known vulnerabilities and exists longer than Cryfs. So for now, it is the better choice. Advantage of Cryfs would be that it also encrypts file sizes and directory structure, which eCryptfs does not. Btw I know your answer is old, it was true at the time. I used Encfs myself for a long time.

Comment: @Heinzi The [audit of eCryptfs'](https://defuse.ca/audits/ecryptfs.htm) only negative part was that it was planned to introduce alternative  stream mode that would have reduced security. Thus it was mentioned in the report as a warning.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to encrypt data stored on the computer, there exists some different choises you can make.  You was offered them when you installed Ubuntu in the first place[1].

## Before you do anything like this, make a back up of your data!  You have been warned!!!

### All Disks

The obvious one, and the most secure, is to encrypt the whole disk[2].  In that way, noone can steal your computer and use any information stored in your computer, like your passwords in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` or look at your temporary files which will give lots of information away.
So to use that, look up `dm-crypt`/`LUKS`/`cryptsetup` for more information.

### Directories in `$HOME`

There are also support for encryption of directories in your `$HOME` directory[3].  Either you can use the older version, which encrypt a separate directory called `$HOME/Private` or you could encrypt whole of your `$HOME`.

To create an encrypted `$HOME/Private`, just run the command

```
ecryptfs-setup-private
```

in a terminal and this should be set up for you.

To encrypt a users `$HOME`, you need to install the package `encryptfs-utils` and then create a *new* user with the command

```
sudo adduser --encrypt-home username
```

where `username` should be the new users login name. You could still make your `$HOME` encrypted after installation, but remember to back up your data before doing this[4].

### Encrypting Removable Disks

Lastly, if you want to encrypt your USB Memory stick, you could do that too.  Just install package `cryptsetup` and partition it with the graphical tool `gnome-disk-utility` or follow the instruktions for doing this from the command line[5].

For more information about encryption of disks and directories, please read here:

1. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemHowto
2. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystems
3. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome
4. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1449168
5. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemsOnRemovableStorage

Comment: can the removable disk be a growable iso? (sparse image)?

Comment: are encrypted folders mountable? how does one access the encrypted data? can the folder be closed or unmounted?

Comment: I can't see any use of ISO, at all. Please explain why you think that you need ISO images? None of these encrypted file systems/directories will not be cross platform anyway, if I understand this properly. I might be wrong, as I am I only interested in Linux system, has not run a MS Windows or Apple OS since 10-15 years back on my own computers. If cross platform is important for you, have a look at `git-annex`

Comment: Please try it out to see if it is anything you would look like to use. If not, just remove it. And a feedback what was good for you would be nice too. :-)

Comment: I need on "iso", per se, just something that functions like one. @Sylwester mentined encfs. I'll try that, and see how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

Because of recently found [security vulnerabilities in Encfs](https://defuse.ca/audits/encfs.htm), I switched to [Cryfs](https://www.cryfs.org) (disclaimer: I'm also one of the developers there). The tool does what you're asking for and has advantages over [eCryptfs](http://ecryptfs.org) or [Encfs](https://vgough.github.io/encfs/).

One advantage is that it also encrypts file sizes and directory structure. With Encfs or eCryptfs, anyone can see your directory structure and file sizes. This often makes more information public than you want to. Say you have a set of directories with ~20 files each and each file ~3MB. This is probably a music CD collection. Or say you store a copy of a Windows 8 DVD in your file system. That is easily figured out by comparing directory structure and file sizes of the Windows 8 DVD with the structure of your encrypted file system.

Cryfs is a quite new project, but I already use it for some time to encrypt my Dropbox folder and didn't have any problems so far.

There is an easy [Tutorial](https://www.cryfs.org/tutorial) to help you get started.